# jQGrid checkbox values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have an editable checkbox in my jQGrid with the values

`editoptions: { value: "Yes:No" }`

But whatever the value is i am getting back on controller string value "Yes:No", not single value "Yes" of "No", so i am getting it like that:

When it is checked i am getting this:

```
form["MyCheckBox"] = "Yes:No".
```

When it is not checked i am getting this:

```
form["MyCheckBox"] = "No".
```

How can i do to make it work?
Or is there any way to get bool values(true/false) instead of string values ?

Need help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
editoptions: { value:"True:False" }, editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', 
formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you describe the bug which is already fixed in the last version of jqGrid from GitHub. I recommend you to download the version from [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid). See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install#development_installation) for the description of the order of the including of the jqGrid moduls.